# How will the new tax bill benefit an S-corp individual?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, s-corporation

While driving, I heard on some news program that flow-through people can deduct more from direct income from their business than indirectly through payroll (such as ADP).  Will the new tax bill let me dump ADP and just transfer my income directory from business to my pocket?

I am a self-employed consultant making about $300k per year, and am my only 'employee' and have to waste time on the 'farce' of payroll in order to save a little when paying taxes.